# PHP: How to select single value from single row in MySQL without using array for results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to PHP and have a really basic question.

If I know the result of a query is only a single value (cell) from a single row in MySQL **how can I simplify the below without having to go through an array of results** and without increasing the risk of SQL injection ?

In the example below I would just need to echo a single email as the result of the query.

I found a couple of posts suggesting different approaches with `fetch_field` for this but I am not sure what is the best way here since some of these seem to be pretty old or deprecated now.

**My PHP:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM Users WHERE userName = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$arr = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $arr["email"];
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid caring what the column is called by just doing this:

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM Users WHERE userName = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
$stmt->execute();

$email = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object()->email;
echo $email;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Does the result always have to be an array here ? I thought instead of fetch() I could use something like fetch_field so that the result is already just a single value instead of an array.

Comment: No problem. Ah, I see. Check out my edit above; this might be a good solution. `fetch_object()` returns an object with the field names as properties, so it can be dereferenced via `->` to get just the `email` field here.